# Performance issues with outer joins to view in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

Two of my clients have recently upgraded to `Oracle 12c 12.1.0.2`.  Since the upgrade I am experiencing significant performance degradation on queries using views with outer joins.  Below is an example of a simple query that runs in seconds on the old `Oracle 11g 11.2.0.2` database but takes several minutes on the new `12c` database.  Even more perplexing, this query runs reasonably fast (but not as fast) on one of the `12c` databases, but not at all on the other.  The performance is so bad on the one `12c` database that the reporting I've developed is unusable.

I've compared indexes and system parameters between the `11g` and two `12c` databases, and have not found any significant differences.  There is a difference between the `Execution Plans`, however.  On `11g` the outer join is represented as `VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE` but on `12c` it is represented as a `HASH JOIN` without the `PUSHED PREDICATE`.

When I add the hint `/*+ NO_MERGE(pt) PUSH_PRED(pt) */` to the query on the `12c` database, then the performance is within seconds.

Adding a hint to the SQL is not an option within our `Crystal Reports` (at least I don't believe so and also there are several reports), so I am hoping we can figure out why performance is acceptable on one 12c database but not on the other.

My team and I are stumped at what to try next, and particularly why the response would be so different between the two `12c` databases.  We have researched several articles on performance degradation in `12c`, but nothing appears particularly applicable to this specific issue.  As an added note, queries using tables instead of views are returning results within an acceptable timeframe.  Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: 11g database]

[image: 12c database]

Query:

```
select pi.*
, pt.*
from policyissuance_oasis pi
, policytransaction_oasis pt
where 
pi.newTranKeyJoin = pt.polTranKeyJoin(+)
and pi.policyNumber = '1-H000133'
and pi.DateChars='08/10/2017 09:24:51'    -- 2016 data
--and pi.DateChars = '09/26/2016 14:29:37'  --2013 data
order by pi.followup_time
```

Comment: These images are unreadable. Please remove the bitmaps from the question and append your queries **using simple text format**. Please also append a definition of the problematic view **as a text, not a bitmap**. Please also append explain plans, **as a text not a bitmap**. To generate the explain plan in a text format use this sequence of steps: `EXPLAIN PLAN FORM select .... your query` then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XLAN.display)`, then copy a result of last query **as a text** and just paste it to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @krokodilko.  I will add the requested text objects as soon as I can figure out the correct formatting!  Sorry, I'm new at this!

Comment: did you gather statistics? I know that question sounds silly, but just to check...

Comment: We need to see your table and index definitions.

Comment: For which table?  There are several in the view.

Comment: @krokodilko, sorry, I tried executing the EXPLAIN PLAN and then SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.display) per your instructions, but received the following error:  "Error: cannot fetch last explain plan from PLAN_TABLE".  Any other ideas as to how I can convey the contents of the explain plan in a text format?

Comment: You must run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR query...` and then **immediately** run `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.display)`. If you run between any other command, then you will get an error. Please read [the documentation of EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered the cause of the performance issue.  The following 2 system parameters were changed at the system level by the DBAs for the main application that uses our client's Oracle server:

```
_optimizer_cost_based_transformation = OFF 
_optimizer_reduce_groupby_key = FALSE
```

When we changed them at the session level to the following, the query above that joins the 2 views returns results in less than 2 seconds:

```
alter session set "_optimizer_cost_based_transformation"=LINEAR;
alter session set "_optimizer_reduce_groupby_key" = TRUE;
COMMIT;
```

Changing this parameter did not have an impact on performance:

```
alter session set optimizer_adaptive_features=FALSE;
COMMIT;
```

We also found that changing the following parameter improved performance even more for our more complex views:

```
alter session set optimizer_features_enable="11.2.0.3";
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

as krokodilko says, perform these :

```
explain plan for 
select pi.*
, pt.*
from policyissuance_oasis pi
, policytransaction_oasis pt
where 
pi.newTranKeyJoin = pt.polTranKeyJoin(+)
and pi.policyNumber = '1-H000133'
and pi.DateChars='08/10/2017 09:24:51'    -- 2016 data
--and pi.DateChars = '09/26/2016 14:29:37'  --2013 data
order by pi.followup_time;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
```

and then, you probably see this at the bottom of the plan :

```
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

there,

> dynamic sampling

concept should be the center of concern for performance problems(level=2 is the default value, ranges between 0-11 ).

In fact, Dynamic sampling (DS) was introduced to improve the optimizer's ability to generate good execution plans. This feature was enhanced and renamed `Dynamic Statistics in Oracle Database 12c`. The most common misconception is that `DS` can be used as a substitute for optimizer statistics, whereas the goal of `DS` is to augment `optimizer statistics`; it is used when `regular statistics` are not sufficient to get good quality cardinality estimates.

For serial SQL statements the `dynamic sampling level` is controlled by the

> optimizer_dynamic_sampling

parameter but note that from `Oracle Database 12c Release 1` the existence of `SQL plan directives` can also initiate `dynamic statistics` gathering when a query is compiled. This is a feature of adaptive statistics and is controlled by the database parameter

> optimizer_adaptive_features (OAF)

in `Oracle Database 12c Release 1` and

> optimizer_adaptive_statistics (OAS)

in `Oracle Database 12c Release 2`.

In other words, from `Oracle Database 12c Release 1`(we also use db12.1.0.2 at office) onwards, `DS` will be used if certain adaptive features are enabled by setting the relevant parameter to `TRUE`.

Serial statements are typically short running and any `DS` overhead at compile time can have a large impact on overall system performance (if statements are frequently hard parsed). For systems that match this profile, setting `OAF=FALSE` is recommended( `alter session set optimizer_adaptive_features=FALSE` notice that

> you shouldn't alter system but session

).

For `Oracle Database 12c Release 2 onwards`, using the default `OAS=FALSE` is recommended.

`Parallel statements` are generally more resource intensive, so it's often worth investing in additional overhead at compile time to potentially find a better `SQL execution plan`.

For `serial type SQL statements`, you may try to manual set the value for `optimizer_dynamic_sampling`(assuming that there were no relevant SQL plan directives).  If we were to issue a similar style of query against a larger table that had the parallel attribute set we can see the dynamic sampling kicking in.

When should you use `dynamic sampling`? `DS` is typically recommended when you know you are getting a bad execution plan due to complex predicates. But shouldn't be system-wide as i mentioned before.

When is it not a good idea to use `dynamic sampling`? 
If the queries compile times need to be as fast as possible, for example, unrepeated `OLTP` queries where you can't amortize the additional cost of compilation over many executions.

> As the last word, for your case, it could be beneficient to set
>   optimizer_adaptive_features parameter to FALSE for individual SQL
>   statements and see the gained results.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Barbaros!  I was able to capture the Plan results per your instructions.  I've updated my post with the text output.  Unfortunately I do not have DBA privileges on the database, but I'm working with our DBA to review and apply your suggestions.  I'll let you know the results soon.

Comment: I was able to capture the Plan results per your instructions, however I'm unable to update my post with the text output as it adds too many characters (there were 260 rows of output).  Please let me know if there's a certain portion that would be more useful to include.